# Position a slide out form on the right edge of the screen

Tags: css

I am able to position the slide out form "schedule a callback" on the right edge of the website for laptop screens. But on a larger desktop screen, it moves to the edge of the monitor and not the edge of the website. I need it to be restricted to the edge of the website. The CSS code I have used for this is

```
    .peeking-form-w .pf-trigger {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    background-color: #2d3091;
    color: #fbaa1b;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(
-90deg
) translate(-50%,-99%);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%,-99%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%,-99%);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%,-99%);
    top: 50%;
    transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

How do I add a media query for larger screens to show the peek out form at the edge of the website and not the monitor/screen of the desktop.
[This image shows how the slide out form moves to the edge of the screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJT8k.jpg)

[This is how the slide out form should be on the edge of the website and should remain here even if the screen size increases.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw3Os.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke media queries in your css. For example you need to decide what to do in mobile devices. See below:

```
@media (max-width: 1600px) {
.peeking-form-w {
DO SOMETHING
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for a quick response. So I will need to specify the position of the peeking form as in terms of x and y axis with respect to the size of the container.